# set dynamic From name and From address for Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, dynamic

I have created a sender profile with Name = %%FromName%% and Address = %%FromEmail%%

I want my triggered send to pick up the sender email address and name from the the row in the same payload.
I want to see if its possible and how can I set it up in Marketing Cloud.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and has been asked many times. Try setting up a sendable Data Extension with "FromName" and "FromEmail". Send a test using your new Sender Profile? Does it work? If not, ask Support to enable the Enhanced Sender Profile Business Rule for you.

If you're sending from a domain other than a SAP/Private Domain configured in SFMC, bear in mind that to be able to get any of these emails to the inbox, you'll need to set up SPF and DKIM DNS records for the domain used by FromEmail. If you use DMARC, you'll need to add ExactTarget servers to the allowed list of senders.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. I used AmpScript to point to the filed in the Trigger De that has the Name and email address!